# When routing in Ember 1.0.0 pre

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to create routing in my ember app with something like the following:

```
app= Ember.Application.create({
        ApplicationController: Ember.ObjectController.extend(),
        ApplicationView: Ember.View.extend(),

        Router: Ember.Router.extend({
            root: Ember.Route.extend({
                route: '/',

                aRoute: Ember.Route.extend({
                    route: '/routeA'
                }),
                bRoute: Ember.Route.extend({
                    route: '/routeB'
                })
            })
        })
});

app.initialize();
```

But when opening the page following error precents it self:

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Could not find state for path
```

When digging a little into the source code of ember, I the "hash" property of location is never set - Should be set when a hash event of some kind is triggered by the browser.

Am I on the right track and how do I solve this problem?
​

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only leaf routes are routable, when entering '/', the router doesn't know where he has to go.
I suggest you defining an index route, which only redirects to a leaf route.
For example:

```
    Router: Ember.Router.extend({
        root: Ember.Route.extend({
            index: Ember.Route.extend({
                route: '/',
                redirectsTo: 'aRoute'
            }),

            aRoute: Ember.Route.extend({
                route: '/routeA'
            }),
            bRoute: Ember.Route.extend({
                route: '/routeB'
            })
        })
    })
```

Comment: I think `redirectsTo` expects the name of the route, i.e. 'aRoute'